# Why requests is getting same data and returning errors from different urls in python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a list of data to scrape here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KMYsjN2ggklFMQ5HPKMbdkVqc04MdjhYGLvku1Js0cc/edit?usp=sharing
So the scraper runs but there are two problems here.

1. The scraper returns the same data for different url, even though when I checked the urls reponse through web is both different and both are returning 200.
   The dictionary ID is a distinct id mapped out to the urls.

| scraped_product_name | url | dictionary_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hansaplast aqua protect 6s | https://www.blibli.com/p/hansaplast-aqua-protect-6s/ps--RAM-70107-07546?ds=RAM-70107-07546-00001&source=MERCHANT_PAGE&sid=7cb21b003f4516bb&cnc=false&pickupPointCode=PP-3239816&pid=RAM-70107-07546 | 418 |
| Hansaplast aqua protect 6s | https://www.blibli.com/p/hansaplast-aqua-protect-6s/ps--RAM-70107-07546?ds=RAM-70107-07546-00001&source=MERCHANT_PAGE&sid=7cb21b003f4516bb&cnc=false&pickupPointCode=PP-3239816&pid=RAM-70107-07546 | 181 |

2. After running a few urls, it returns an error Access Denied where there is no data. I was wondering if this affects the data being returned?However when I tried rerunning it again in another iteration it returns a 200.

Here's my code

```
from random import randint
import requests

rancherrors=pd.DataFrame()
ranchdf=pd.DataFrame()
for id, input,url in zip(ranch['product_id'],ranch['urls'],ranch['urls2']):
    
    headers={
        "user-agent" : f"{UserAgent().random}",
        'referer':'https://www.blibli.com/'
        }
    response =requests.get(url,headers=headers,verify=True)
    #catches error
    ####################
    if response.status_code != 200:
        datum={
            'id':id,
            'url':url,
        'date_key':today
        }
        rancherrors=rancherrors.append(pd.DataFrame([datum]))
        print(f'{url} error')

        sleep(randint(5,15))

    else:
    #runs scraper
    ################################
        try:
            price=str(response.json()['data']['price']['listed']).replace(".0","")
            discount=str(response.json()['data']['price']['totalDiscount'])
        except:
            price="0"
            discount="0"
        try:
            unit=str(response.json()['data']['uniqueSellingPoint']).replace("• ","")
        except:
            unit=""

        datranch={
            'product_name':response.json()['data']['name'],
            'normal_price':price,
            'discount':discount,
            'competitor_id':response.json()['data']['ean'],
            'url':input,
            'unit':unit,
            'product_id':id,
            'date_key':today,
            'web':'ranch market'
            }
        ranchdf=ranchdf.append(pd.DataFrame([datranch]))
```

I use the rancherrors to catch errors and run in loop until no errors appears.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: so there are 2 things that's going on, if it's 200 some items are being returned the same json file for different sites (even though when opened in the browser it's different) and the error returns an Access Denied, but when rerun in another iteration it returns a 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have duplicated values in the url2 column in your examples list, and such same data is scraped. Few highlighted duplicates can be seen in below image:
   [image: Duplicate URLs]

2. Don't refresh the User-Agent from the Header at every call. The User-Agent identifies the application, operating system, vendor, and/or version of the requesting user. As you are not using proxies and are making a call from the same IP address, changing these details every second is very suspicious. Try moving the Headers initialization outside your for loop at the start:

   ```
   ...
   ranchdf=pd.DataFrame()
   headers={
        "user-agent" : f"{UserAgent().random}",
        'referer':'https://www.blibli.com/'
        }
   for id, input,url in zip(ranch['product_id'],ranch['urls'],ranch['urls2']):

        response =requests.get(url,headers=headers,verify=True)
   ...
   ```

A chance of being denied will still be there but it should be much better. For better avoiding bans you would need to make use of proxies as well.